# In blender time line how can I control which frame I want to show/not show?

Tags: animation, dopesheet, timeline

I rotoscoped a video animation using the grease pencil, and I would like to start messing with the timings. How do you hide certain frames without deleting them?

Comment: I guess you could make use of this [retime script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82381/30849)

Comment: rotoscope, as in using grease pencil or what?

Comment: @cegaton yes I was using grease pencil to draw over the model.